# Can I define variables in an ansible role/task file without a block?

Tags: ansible

I have a role, which contains a file with tasks. A variable is used by all tasks in that file.

```
---
vars:
  name: john

- name: say hello
  debug:
    msg: "{{name}} says hello"

- name: say goodbye
  debug:
    msg: "{{name}} says goodbye"
```

That doesn't work. But I can make it work by:

- moving everything into a `block`
- using `set_fact`, but that leaks the variable to the entire playbook (not what I want)

*Can I somehow do this without a block?*

(I find the block-in-block-in-foo-in-bar messy, and sometimes I don't want to split into multiple files.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your roles variables should be stored in a YAML file under `roles/your_pretty_role/vars/`.

In that directory, the `main.yml` is automatically loaded. So in `roles/your_pretty_role/vars/main.yml`:

```
---
name: john
```

And in your `roles/your_pretty_role/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: say hello
  debug:
    msg: "{{name}} says hello"

- name: say goodbye
  debug:
    msg: "{{name}} says goodbye"
```

Now, let's say you don't need those variables in the entire role, you can eventually split the variables in other YAML files in that directory but in that case, you will have to include them simply with a `include_vars: <file>.yml`. So move your var in `roles/your_pretty_role/vars/hello.yml`:

```
---
name: mike
```

And in the desired tasks file you will have to add the include:

```
- name: Include needed variables
  include_vars: hello.yml

- name: say hello
  debug:
    msg: "{{name}} says hello"

- name: say goodbye
  debug:
    msg: "{{name}} says goodbye"
```

You can also declare default variables in roles. Those have a very low precedence and can be overwritten easily. Those have to be stored in `roles/your_pretty_role/defaults/main.yml`.

### Doc

Here is the Ansible doc about that:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles

Comment: Thanks. But that variable becomes available to everything in the role, whereas what I'm asking is about a variable that is scoped to that file (or block) only. Is there no way to do that other than what you proposed?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with the `include_vars`. Just put the variables in a separated file `vars/hello.yml`. This one will not be loaded by default by the role (only `vars/main.yml` is). So in the tasks file you want to get those variable you will have to explicitly add a task `- include_vars: hello.yml`. As far as I understand, this answers your need.

Comment: It's unfortunate the variables cannot be scoped in the same way they would be when programming. The ansible way is so messy, but your way is a nice workaround. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer like that the example with the include_vars fits better your need.

Comment: BTW, it's more than a workaround, it's a feature, it's how the role's vars are designed to be used. You could have a look on the roles provided on Galaxy. You will find tons of example. [Here is one](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-ntp/blob/master/tasks/main.yml#L2) from Jeff Geerling, to import OS-specific variables.

Comment: Thanks again, this really helps! BTW you are right it's not a "workaround" it's a feature - but I'm still new to ansible, and judging it with new eyes, a lot of what I see is messy. I think the API was not evolved cleanly. That said, ansible is incredibly powerful, so if it works, it works!

Comment: @xenlo Can we reference other vars, including set with defaults like `archived_file_path: "{{ archive_base_dir }}/{{ temp_zip_name }}"` ??